# Example of an infinitely differentiable function f : R → R with f(x) = 0 iff x = 0 and f intersects origin with infinite multiplicity

Tags: functions

Is there an infinitely differentiable function f : R → R with
f(x) = 0 iff x = 0 for which it is reasonable to say the graph of f intersects
the x-axis at the origin with infinite multiplicity. So y=x, y=x^2 does not count.

Comment: As in $f(x) = x$?

Comment: Question is edited

Comment: I think that considering the Taylor series of such a function would show that the desired function has to be identically zero, contrary to your hopes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2}& x \neq 0 \cr 0 & x = 0\end{cases}$

looks like it does the trick. It's a standard proof by induction that it's smooth and that its Maclaurin series is identically zero.